# Akka system config in library affecting app

Tags: scala, akka

I have a published library that uses Akka HTTP under the hood. I don't want the library to block termination of apps, so [I configure the library's ActorSystem to be daemonic](https://github.com/Synesso/scala-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L1). The [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/general/configuration.html) explicitly say that libraries should do this in `reference.conf`

> If you are writing an Akka-based library, keep its configuration in reference.conf at the root of the JAR file.

When I use this library in an app which has its own ActorSystem, I want that system to have the default non-daemonic behaviour. Unfortunately the configuration from the library applies to ActorSystems created throughout the app.

For example, this main method that uses my library will terminate immediately:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("stellar-channels")
    import system.dispatcher

    TestNetwork.fund(KeyPair.random)
  }
}
```

The creation of the `ActorSystem` should have ensured that it would block until `system.terminate()` was called. But the configuration of the library has affected `ActorSystem("stellar-channels")` also.

Is there a way I can apply the library's config to just the ActorSystem used by the library, without forcing app writers to reconfigure their own ActorSystems back to defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the configuration for each system, you can use `lift-a-subtree` trick of typesafe config.

E.g.

In your library, you may can write your `application.conf` as follows:

```
mylibrary {
  akka.loglevel = "WARNING"
  my.own.setting = 43
}
```

Main scala code:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val app1 = ActorSystem("MyLib", config.getConfig("mylibrary").withFallback(config))
```

With this trick, you application actorsystem will never get the actorsystem settings of your lib unless you explicitly do it. Then the lib will not affect the app.

Detail refers to [akka guide](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#configuring-multiple-actorsystem).